# Sejda HTML to PDF : how to keep thead on all pages where a table is displayed?

Tags: pdf-generation, sejda

I'm using **SEJDA API** with PHP to **convert HTML to PDF**.
In this HTML, I have multiple tables with a variable number of rows, and each of them have a variable height, with a variable number of columns, etc.

Sometimes one (or more) table is long enough to be displayed on more than one page, so I can have a page with only rows of `tbody` but no `thead` "labels" to tell what each columns can represents.

Is there a proper way to force the `thead` to be shown on each page where the table is displayed ? The "css position:fixed" solution is not a good way because there is potentially more than one table and not all pages have a table on it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your print styles:

```
thead {display: table-header-group;}
```

If your still having issues, try https://docamatic.com. There is a dynamic table template (JSON to PDF).

Comment: Didn't work unfortunally ! I'll take a loot at docamatic, thanks :)